# Running CodeIgniter Project

Tags: php, codeigniter, frameworks, codeigniter-2

I have a Whole web site project based on CodeIgniter framework. My problem is i don't know how to run this project on my local Mamp Server. I have Successfully set up Mamp and Also run the latest version of CodeIgniter. [image]

But now how can i run the whole project using CodeIgniter found in my localhost folder. This is my first experience with a CMS Framework.

Comment: You're already running it. The big issue here is that Codeigniter IS NOT a CMS, it's a framework, i.e. a collection of tools to build any kind of websites (a CMS too). You might have been expecting something else?

Comment: Have a look in the tutorial. https://phpacademy.org/tutorial/introduction-to-codeigniter-basic-website

Comment: @ Damien Pirsy you're right, sorry for my lack of precision and knowledge. @ Sharif Ul Islam thanks i'll take a look at the tutorial :)

Comment: @Dimitri, you are creating a new Project, or you have to run an existing project?

Comment: @Nishant, i have an existing project

Comment: then why are you setting up a new codeigniter. you just have to create a virtual host and take a new checkout and point your virtual host to the checkout

Comment: how to achieve this ? i am new to this type of development do you have a tutorial to follow ?

Comment: @dimitri which enviornment are you using for development? linux or windows

Comment: @Nishant : I have a macBook pro with Mamp

Comment: Have you solved this issue?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Open application/config folder**

> *First go to config.php file and point the base url to the correct location*
>
> $config['base_url']    = '';
>
> than goes to the database.php and provide correct database parameters
>
> $db['default']['hostname'] = 'localhost';
>
> $db['default']['username'] = 'user';
>
> $db['default']['password'] = 'password';
>
> $db['default']['database'] = 'dbname';
>
> thats the most basic changes u have to do....
>
> now if you want to redirect it to specific controller by default go to routes.php file in config directory and change this vairable
> $route['default_controller'] = "yourcontrollername"

Comment: is this ok http://mrforbes.com/blog/2009/02/setting-up-a-local-code-igniter-dev-environment-osx/

Comment: i did what you said i got the following error : 404 Page Not Found
The page you requested was not found.

Answer (score 1):

At first config your site settings using **config.php** and also for database settings edit the **database.php** and then in file router.php file give the default controller name for your site

```
$route['default_controller'] = 'login';
```

that will help to open an controller on the first loading of the project like login page or homepage etc,and then open your website like

```
http://your_ip/project_folder_name/
```

then it will directly open your default controller page.I think it will help for you as well.these are the very basic things that can help you to run the project ,glad that you are working on CodeIgniter,this framework is very flexible and easy to learn,enjoy to work on this

Comment: thanks you it help me a lot but i am having 404 Page Not Found
The page you requested was not found. i believe this have to do with .htaccess

Answer (score 0):

Use localhost/name_of_the_codeigniter_folder_inside_htdocs/index.php/name_of_the_controller_file_you_want_to_execute/name_of_the_function_inside_the_file_which_you_want_to_execute

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

You can run the CI project by starting your server and just type this in your broser -

```
localhost/folderName
```